Is there a Component to make a canvas that can make drawings?
I have been making image generator, And I need to make a way to create images with drawing and without URLs, Is there a thing to solve this?
Like a brush tool?
I made this code that can make plain colored images:
String files = "D:/ImgGen/" + field.getText();
File folder = new File(files);
if (!folder.exists()){
    folder.mkdirs();
}
                
int width = 16;
int height = 16;
                
BufferedImage bufferedImage;
                
for (int i = 0; i < slider.getValue(); i++) {
    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
}

Is there a way to make the thing drawn like the Paint programs?

This question is similar to: What is the simplest way to draw in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to draw in JPanel? (Swing/graphics Java). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Performing Custom Painting section.
